# Testing AJAX post in TestApp and Pyramid

Tags: python, ajax, pyramid

I'm trying to write a test for an ajax view...The view is configured like so:

```
@view_config(name='new', context='resource.Events', renderer='json',
             request_method='POST', xhr=True)
def event_view(self):
    # ...
```

In my test, I want to create an ajax post so I try:

```
extra_environ = {'X_REQUESTED_WITH' : 'XmlHttpRequest'}
# also tried setting HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH

self.testapp.post('/events/new', params=post_params, extra_environ=extra_environ)
```

But the post never gets routed to my view.  The request.is_xhr param never gets set to True.

Should be a simple answer somewhere, but I could not find it in any of the docs, or elsewhere.  Can anyone recommend how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I wasn't casing 'xmlhttprequest' correctly.  Needs to be:

```
extra_environ = {'HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH' : 'XMLHttpRequest'}
```

Found this in the code at:

webob/request.py line 472

Unfortunate to need to dig around in the code for this.  Also surprised case matters.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was simply enough to set **xhr=True** in post request.

```
self.testapp.post('/events/new', params=post_params, xhr=True)
```